# disabled output_buffering in php error

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a project that have problem and error message like this.

```
 `Please config php.ini (output_buffering=4096)`
```

how can i fix this error please help. 
Please visit this link http://www.caminnotec.com/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are running on Hostblast, but cannot tell what kind of environment you are using. If you are using shared hosting, I doubt you would be able to edit your `php.ini` file, or use a custom one. As such, you would need to do this using `.htaccess`. I have also checked, and you are running PHP on Apache. The following should work for you:

```bash
php_value output_buffering 4096
```

Place this at the top of your `.htaccess` file, and then try loading the page again. If this does not work as intended, then you will need to contact your host to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says.  Find the location of your `php.ini` file (your host may be able to help) and edit the value of `output_buffering` so it equals 4096.

If it isn't already in php.ini simply add this line:

```
output_buffering=4096
```

Find a bit more information here: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php.ini-directives/php-output_buffering-directive

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn off output buffering in `php.ini` file:

```
output_buffering = off
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Comment: I do think that the message is somewhat vague, but I believe that the implication here is to set it to `4096`, and not to turn it off.

Comment: @MikeRockett Could you please write this on the 1st line and check if the error is getting resolved? init_set("output_buffering", 4096);

Comment: Uhm, this is not my question - the OP must do this, not me.

Comment: And it's not `init_set`, it's `ini_set`.

Comment: @MikeRockett sorry. My mistake. Had posted using mobile hence the mistake. Thanks for the correction.